# Open query in design view, edit, then pull results

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Just wondering if anyone could help me out on this problem. I'm making a macro in excel that opens a query in design view so I can edit it. Then run the query and pull in the results. Unfortunately, I keep getting error that says this recordset is uneditable. The code is below.

```
'connect to Access Database
Application.StatusBar = "Connecting to Access database..."
Const DbLoc As String = "I:\Ben\New Stores\Reports\Scratch Reporting DB.accdb"
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim recCount As Long
Set db = OpenDatabase(DbLoc)
Set objAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
With objAccess
    .opencurrentdatabase (DbLoc)
    .docmd.openquery "OOS by DC5"
    .docmd.openquery "Today2"
    .docmd.openquery "Today2_intrans"
    .docmd.openquery "Today7"
    .docmd.openquery "Today7_InTrans"
    .docmd.openquery "OOS by Dept_Final", acViewDesign
End With

Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset("OOS by DC5", dbOpenSnapshot)
Set rs2 = db.OpenRecordset("Today7_InTrans", dbOpenSnapshot)
Set rs3 = db.OpenRecordset("Today7", dbOpenSnapshot)
Set rs4 = db.OpenRecordset("OOS by Dept_Final", dbOpenSnapshot)

'copy recordset to spreadsheet
Application.StatusBar = "Writing Access data to spreadsheet..."
If rs1.RecordCount = 0 Then
MsgBox "No data retrieved from database", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "No Data"
GoTo Subexit
Else
rs1.MoveLast
recCount = rs1.RecordCount
rs1.MoveFirst
End If
ws11.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs1
ws11.Range("B" & recCount + 1).Formula = "=SUM(B1:B" & recCount & ")"
ws11.Range("C" & recCount + 1).Formula = "=SUM(C1:C" & recCount & ")"
ws18.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs2
ws19.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs3
ws8.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs4
```

Note; this is a snippet of the entire macro so my variables aren't declared here. Thank you for your help in advance!

SQL BEFORE

```
SELECT [OOS by Dept2].MaxOfDept, [dept name].[Department Name], [OOS by Dept2].[17935] AS Expr1, [OOS by Dept2].[18363] AS Expr2, [OOS by Dept2].[18455], [OOS by Dept2].[18584] AS Expr3, [OOS by Dept2].[18593] AS Expr4, [OOS by Dept2].[18638] AS Expr5, [OOS by Dept2].[18649], [OOS by Dept2].[18695] AS Expr6, [OOS by Dept2].[18696], [OOS by Dept2].[18712], [OOS by Dept2].[18810] AS Expr7, [OOS by Dept2].[18919], [OOS by Dept2].[18990] AS Expr8, [OOS by Dept2].[19720]
FROM [OOS by Dept2] LEFT JOIN [dept name] ON [OOS by Dept2].MaxOfDept = [dept name].Dept
GROUP BY [OOS by Dept2].MaxOfDept, [dept name].[Department Name], [OOS by Dept2].[17935], [OOS by Dept2].[18363], [OOS by Dept2].[18455], [OOS by Dept2].[18584], [OOS by Dept2].[18593], [OOS by Dept2].[18638], [OOS by Dept2].[18649], [OOS by Dept2].[18695], [OOS by Dept2].[18696], [OOS by Dept2].[18712], [OOS by Dept2].[18810], [OOS by Dept2].[18919], [OOS by Dept2].[18990], [OOS by Dept2].[19720];
```

SQL AFTER

```
SELECT [OOS by Dept2].MaxOfDept, [dept name].[Department Name], [OOS by Dept2].[17052], [OOS by Dept2].[18220], [OOS by Dept2].[18272], [OOS by Dept2].[18455], [OOS by Dept2].[18614], [OOS by Dept2].[18633], [OOS by Dept2].[18645], [OOS by Dept2].[18649], [OOS by Dept2].[18696], [OOS by Dept2].[18712], [OOS by Dept2].[18919], [OOS by Dept2].[19720]
FROM [OOS by Dept2] LEFT JOIN [dept name] ON [OOS by Dept2].MaxOfDept = [dept name].Dept
GROUP BY [OOS by Dept2].MaxOfDept, [dept name].[Department Name], [OOS by Dept2].[17052], [OOS by Dept2].[18220], [OOS by Dept2].[18272], [OOS by Dept2].[18455], [OOS by Dept2].[18614], [OOS by Dept2].[18633], [OOS by Dept2].[18645], [OOS by Dept2].[18649], [OOS by Dept2].[18696], [OOS by Dept2].[18712], [OOS by Dept2].[18919], [OOS by Dept2].[19720];
```

SQL Constant

```
SELECT [OOS by Dept2].MaxOfDept, [dept name].[Department Name]
FROM [OOS by Dept2] LEFT JOIN [dept name] ON [OOS by Dept2].MaxOfDept = [dept name].Dept
GROUP BY [OOS by Dept2].MaxOfDept, [dept name].[Department Name];
```

Comment: Where is your code to edit the query? What line causes the error? Is it this one `docmd.openquery "OOS by Dept_Final", acViewDesign`

Comment: Yes, that is the line that is supposed to open the query so I can edit it and is also where I am getting the error code.

Comment: That will try and open the query in design mode inside Access - not sure that's what you're looking for? You can change the SQL by creating a Querydef object and referencing it with `Set qdf = db.Querydefs("OOS by Dept_Final")` then change the SQL by `qdf.SQL = "new sql"`

Comment: Do you mind posting an example of this? I'm open to this but I'm not 100% on execution. How I manually update this query is by opening (OOS by Dept_Final) in design view, delete everything in the third column over, then drag down new values from a linked table in its place. So... how would I get my "new sql" from this changing table? P.S. sorry if this isn't crystal clear... let me know if you have any questions. Thanks!

Comment: In Design mode, click View | SQL and copy /paste the SQL into your question - before and after your changes to the query. Is the linked table name always the same? Are the fields from the linked table always the same?

Comment: The linked table name is always the same yes but the fields change dramatically every week. I have added the before and after SQL thanks!

Comment: Are you adding all the fields each time - it;s just that the field names change?

Comment: Correct. When I first open in design view I delete everything in the third column & to the right. The SQL in the first two columns remains unchanged and I have added to my question under SQL constant. After that I add all the store numbers that are listed in the linked table (which changes every week)

Comment: Okay - added an answer to programatically change your query SQL. Should be a start anyways

Comment: Wow this is an awesome start! So... I commented out tdf.Close because it said 'method or data member not found'. Now the line Set tdf = db.TableDefs("OOS by Dept2") is getting error 'Item not found in this collection'. I added .docmd.openquery "OOS by Dept2" above without any luck of fixing this error. Any ideas?

Comment: "OOS by Dept2" must be  a query then? I assumed it was a table

Comment: Yes, sorry for not clarifying that earlier.

Comment: Also something strange to note is line 'For iField = 1 To qdf2.Fields.Count....' Opens a document in read only format. Not sure why this is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this should work for you

**Add these lines to the top of your declares**

```
Const QDF_MODIFY    As String = "OOS by Dept_Final"

Const BASIC_FIELDS  As String = "SELECT dept2.MaxOfDept, deptname.[Department Name]<INSERT FIELDS> "
Const BASIC_SQL As String = "FROM [OOS by Dept2] AS dept2 LEFT JOIN [dept name] AS deptname ON dept2.MaxOfDept = deptname.Dept "
Const GROUPBY_FIELDS As String = "GROUP BY dept2.MaxOfDept, deptname.[Department Name] <INSERT FIELDS> "
```

**Add these lines to your declare section**

```
' Add these lines to top
Dim qdf  As DAO.QueryDef
Dim qdf2 As DAO.QueryDef

Dim strNewFields As String
Dim strNewSQL As String
Dim iField  As Integer
```

**Remove this line**

```
'.docmd.openquery "OOS by Dept_Final", acViewDesign
```

**Ater** `End With` **Add this code to change your SQL**

```
' Change these to Querydef qdf2 references
Set qdf2 = db.QueryDefs("OOS by Dept2")
' Zero based index - ignore first field MaxOfDept
For iField = 1 To qdf2.Fields.Count - 1
    strNewFields = strNewFields & ", dept2.[" & qdf2.Fields(iField).Name & "]"
Next
qdf2.Close

' Insert new fields and rebuild SQL
strNewSQL = Replace(BASIC_FIELDS, "<INSERT FIELDS>", strNewFields)
strNewSQL = strNewSQL & BASIC_SQL
strNewSQL = strNewSQL & Replace(GROUPBY_FIELDS, "<INSERT FIELDS>", strNewFields)
Debug.Print strNewFields

' Replace the SQL
Set qdf = db.QueryDefs(QDF_MODIFY)
qdf.SQL = strNewSQL
qdf.Close
```

Comment: @Mnathan modified code to use Querydef qdf2 instead of Tabledef tdf

Comment: Ah I see... so now i'm getting object variable not set error on line 'strNewFields = strNewFields &..." @dbmitch

Comment: Change `qdf` to `qdf2`

Comment: awesome! Just a few things before I mark your answer. 1) Still not sure why that workbook opens while the code is working with access...could be that it's linked to the database and that's how the query is updated? Not sure... and 2) The very end of my macro closes and saves the reporting document 'wb4.close (true)' but when trying to run that code I get a runtime error 'Automation Error' message. Any ideas why this would happen/how to fix it?

Comment: What workbook? Where is wb4.close in your code? What line gets Automation error? I think you need to create a new question

Comment: OH and one more thing...anyway to pull in the column headers along with the data? Thanks!

Comment: Yah you're probably right... Just didn't want to post a super long code question for something seemingly so small. Thanks so much for your help Dbmitch

Comment: You can get Field names from the same qdf2.Fields array - just use .Name after the array index refererence

Comment: So add .Name after strNewFields = strNewFields line? Sorry still kind of a beginner and not fluent on terminology.

Comment: You can google or add a new question how to add a header line from copyfromrecordset - you need to copy all the field names `qdf2.Fields(iField).Name`to cells in top row - right now you're inserting  your data into A1 not A2 so there's no room